# Cucumber cannot find feature files on the classpath when compiled as a .war

Tags: java, spring-boot, jboss, cucumber

I'm trying to configure Cucumber testing that will run inside a .war deployed on JBoss. This set-up uses a Controller to kickoff the Cucumber Main. Cucumber requires parameters for the glue path (-g) and the feature file path. Ordinarily, these paths may be preceded by *classpath:*, and .feature files (and step definitions) are properly identified by Cucumber (whether run locally, or in a compiled .jar file). However, when compiling into a .war file, the following exception is thrown:

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException: Provider "vfs" not installed
```

Debugging the project, Cucumber is looking for the feature here:

```
vfs:/C:/Users/{user}/EAP-7.1.0/bin/content/war-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/classes/features/
```

Aside from the 'vfs' not being installed, there is not /content folder in /bin/ location. When looking for how files in the resources location *should* be loaded, the following works:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/features/Test.feature");
```

However, when I pass */features* as the feature location, Cucumber looks in C:/features. I have no power over how Cucumber decides to load its resources. Is there a proper way to pass the feature path such that the features are loaded correctly?

I prepared the following *basic* project that recreates the issue:
https://github.com/bgagnon93/cucumber-war

I am running the cucumber-war.war on a local Red Hat JBoss EAP 7.1 server. After initiating the run on the server, the webapp is accessed on the localhost:
http://localhost:8080/cucumber-war-1.0-SNAPSHOT/

Clicking on the 'start' button will kickoff Cucumber, and cause the failure.

Here is what the Cucumber kickoff looks like in the PortalController class:

```
@PostMapping("/")
public String run() {
    String[] cucumberArgs = {
            "-g", "classpath:com/automation/steps",
            "--tags", "@Test",
            "classpath:features"
    };
    Main.run(cucumberArgs, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    return "test";
}
```

Is there a proper way to pass the feature path such that the features are loaded correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You're are providing the correct path.

Cucumber uses JSR203 to scan for feature files. Currently Apaches VFS doesn't support JSR203. You may however have some luck with [vfs2nio](https://github.com/sshtools/vfs2nio).

Comment: That project doesn't appear on mvn, and the tests fail when I try to package it locally. Am I looking at this all wrong?

Comment: It compiles for me. Can't tell you anything else. Haven't used JBoss since 2016.